# SVN in Eclipse appends numbers to my directories and files

Tags: eclipse, svn

I commit my Play 2.0 application to my repository and it appends numbers to my folders and files once committed. Is this normal? What can I do to prevent this?

Like this:

```
Scala Project 1
 .settings 2
 app 2
 conf 2
```

etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the last revision of the file or folder loaded in the workspace. You can configure these label decorations under *Window - Preferences - Team - SVN - Label decorations*.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers appended to the filenames in Eclipse are the current revision numbers of each of the files in Subversion.